# Submit form to parent window WITHOUT Javascript

Tags: asp.net, html

The application I am developing needs to work in a browser without javascript.  At one point I use an a_link to open a popup window (using target="_newname").  On that page I present a form which I need then to be submitted to the parent windows page.

tried `<form target="_parent">` without success, all the information I can find online is about using Javascript to achieve this!

Using asp.net webforms if that helps at all!

Comment: `_parent` targets the parent frame. Plain HTML has no concept of a parent *window*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this without resorting to javascript. Your best bet is to use a div (e.g. through an asp:Panel) styled like a popup instead of an actual popup; this way, everything stays within the same form, and triggering a postback in the 'popup' also posts the main document.

Comment: The suggested way as you say is javascript... my final solution was to create a dropdownlist on the page in the form:

<listbox> <select button> or <textbox>

select button does postback and populates other fields on page based on Listbox selection... if Javascript is enabled it hides the 

<listbox> <select> or so that just the AutoComplete Textbox is visible.

Answer (score 0):

eeeuuucccchhhhh - only solution I can think of is framesets where you can avoid using javascript...

you SHOULD be opeining popup windows with javascript anyway (not target="_blank") as it is a document effect.

If you have to avoid using javascript then I'd suggest get rid of the popup - have the form open up in the current browser window and submit to previous page.